# Splash while native is loading in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been dabbling around with the Vuforia AR API, and creating some 3D models. Now what they need is a .obj file thats transformed into .h file, with all the appropriate info, and these .h files are loaded at the activity start-up. In this particular case, I'm loading up like 20MB of native files.

Well during this loading, the screen is just dark. No splash screen, no loading screen, no nothing. I was wondering, maybe there is a way to show some sort of a splash screen while these native resources are loading up?

Comment: This seems to have been the problem with the initial loading of the app, since the successive ones load up really fast. A VERY minor delay compared to non-native apps. I'll continue working on this to see if this is a true problem.

Comment: I think you can offload System.loadLibrary in a seperate thread.  After the first time, the system will cache the library.